# ErrorException Undefined variable $k1

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning laravel but there is always a problem
I have defined the value k1 but there is alwalys undefinded problem

this is my controller

```
class DozentController extends Controller
{
    // sql query from datebase
    public  function  number()
    {
        $questions =  DB::table('questions')->count('id');
        $kapitel1 = DB::table('questions')->where('chapters_id','1')->count('id');
        $kapitel2 = DB::table('questions')->where('chapters_id','2')->count('id');
        $kapitel3 = DB::table('questions')->where('chapters_id','3')->count('id');
        $kapitel4 = DB::table('questions')->where('chapters_id','4')->count('id');
        $kapitel5 = DB::table('questions')->where('chapters_id','5')->count('id');
        $kapitel6 = DB::table('questions')->where('chapters_id','6')->count('id');
        $kapitel7 = DB::table('questions')->where('chapters_id','7')->count('id');
        $kapitel8 = DB::table('questions')->where('chapters_id','8')->count('id');
        $kapitel9 = DB::table('questions')->where('chapters_id','9')->count('id');


        return  view('/statisticsA',['question'  =>  $questions , 'group' => $groups , 'k1' => $kapitel1 ,
         'k2' => $kapitel2 , 'k3' => $kapitel3 , 'k4' => $kapitel4 , 'k5' => $kapitel5 , 
         'k6' => $kapitel6 , 'k7' => $kapitel7 , 'k8' => $kapitel8 , 'k9' => $kapitel9]);
    }
}
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('/statisticsA', 'DozentController@number');
Route::get('/statisticsA', [
    'uses' => 'PagesController@getStatisticsAdmin',
    'as' => 'statisticsA',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => ['Author','Admin']
])->middleware('auth');
```

and my blade

```
<div>Die Anzahl von Fragen für Kapitel 1</div> 
                    <p> {{ $k1 }} </p>
```

Comment: You have two identical routes?

Comment: You can do one query less by `$questions = array_sum($kapitel1, $kapitel2, $kapitel3, $kapitel4, $kapitel5, $kapitel6, $kapitel7, $kapitel8, $kapitel9);`

Comment: Can't you just do `$questions = DB::table('questions')->selectRaw('COUNT(id) AS amount')->groupByRaw('chapters_id WITH ROLLUP')`?

Comment: I try but it didnt work

Comment: u just want count just according condiiton?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didnt work"? Was there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with a single query

```php
$questions = DB::table('questions')->selectRaw('COUNT(chapters_id) AS total, chapters_id')->groupBy('chapters_id', 'asc');
```

SQL would be:

```sql
SELECT chapters_id, COUNT(chapters_id) as total FROM questions GROUP BY chapters_id;
```

This will give you count by chapters.

Also in your case the second route would not work. As Laravel will never see this route while parsing so your `PagesController@getStatisticsAdmin`  will never catch the result.

```
Route::get('/statisticsA', [
    'uses' => 'PagesController@getStatisticsAdmin',
    'as' => 'statisticsA',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => ['Author','Admin']
])->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: I try but it still doesn't work, the point is, that I need PagesController. it is related to other page

Comment: Is there a problem in route or controller, I was so confused tried so many times but still doesn't work, I think the path is right but always the same error

Comment: @Esoteriker No just use ```dd($question)``` and you will see that $k1 no longer exists but you will get count according to chapters so now you can use loop intead of using variables for each and every chapters